# Need one example of osgi web example

Tags: osgi

Can any one give one example of how OSGi is implemented for WEB-apps.
For example, One page will have some block where other extensions can contribute to it.

It helps me in understanding the OSGI concepts.
Thanks

Comment: there is no "this is how web-engineering is done in OSGi", it depends  depends largely on your specific use-case, on the OSGi container, the web-framework and web-server you intend to use. could you be more specific?

Comment: This is where I am stuck, I want to build one web application on this manner. I am using eclipse Juno with built in server.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example OSGi web app: https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/showcase.
It uses RESTful web services (implemented as OSGi services) built on top of Amdatu and Angular.js for the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the samples of Pax Web. 
These can be found [here](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples)

Answer (score 1):

My [OSGi for mere mortals](https://github.com/bdelacretaz/OSGi-for-mere-mortals) sample might help, it's a minimal example built from scratch that uses OSGi Declarative Services to provide plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a great and official OSGi example created by Peter Kriens. 
It is showing the whole way of doing OSGi for the web.
[Git Repo](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.blog) and here are the slide [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/web-applications-made-simple-with-osgi-peter-kriens).
The repo contains the different steps from the tutorial as branches.